# Populate Vuejs input field with Firebase when Variables are out of scope

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuefire

I understand that Firebase returns data asynchronously, so I actually **placed the variable inside** the `once()` function. But I cannot access the variable 
 called **`whatever`**. While writing this question I also figured I could try set the firebase data directly to the `data()`.

My question is **how can I pass the data in VueJS data() function so that when the user either refreshes or logs back in the data populates the input field in these two different options?**

```
 <template lang="html">
        <div class="">
              <label for="">Name</label>
              <input id="nameId" type="text" v-model="name" />
        </div>
    </template>


export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      name: '',
    }
  },
  methods:{
    var whatever = [];

    var query = dbRef.orderByKey();
    query.once('value')
         .then(function (snapshot) {
             snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                 var childData = childSnapshot.child('name').val();
                 this.whatever.push(childData);

                 // Option 1: use out of scope 
                 this.name = whatever;

                 // Option 2: directly populate data
                 this.name = childData;

             });
         });


}
```

Comment: That's not valid javascript.

Comment: that doesn't help much :(

Comment: You don't have a method defined in the methods block. All of that code that's in the methods block now, wrap it in a named function. But still that needs to be called at some point right. So either call it from a mounted lifecycle method, or just don't use a method, use a computed property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, which incorporates the changes from my comment. To clarify, using a computed property to execute the query would be ideal, as it will execute at a certain point in the lifecycle.

You can also use a method but you would have to call it at some point - you mention on page reload, then one of the component lifecycle hooks would be ideal.

The below is a computed property approach. The property is bound to a v-model so Vue might also force you to define a setter also but that's straightforward.

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    fullName() {
      var query = dbRef.orderByKey();
      query.once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            this.name = childSnapshot.child('name').val();
          });
        });
    }
  }
}


<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <label for="">Name</label>
    <input id="nameId" type="text" v-model="fullName" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi 8bit! thanks!! I placed it in the computed properties...as it definitely makes more sense. However nothing happens, the "this.name" doesn't in the method shows a typeerror "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined". How can I get that value from Firebase to get passed into "name"? Thx again!

Comment: In other words, there seems to be a scope problem right?..where "this.name" doesn't find the data in the vue instance.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use arrow functions as they will make sure that "this" propagates from the enclosing scope of the arrow function. "This" should now point to the component instance, and should have access to the data property name.

Comment: Yess!! That did it! @8bit thankss!! I also moved that function to the "created()" lifecycle hook in order to load the existing data from firebase when the user logs back in!